# Can anyone explain sentences like “it’s two things” “video games are a great source of learning”

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, sentence

These are sentences I’ve seen that don’t seem to follow the singular-plural rules
Are they grammatically correct? If they are how do they work exactly?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is very basic. In English, the verb agrees with the subject. The respective subjects are "It" and "video games."

Comment: But they don’t. What I’m asking is, why is “two things” considered as a singular noun (as “it’s” is used)? And why “video games are a great source of learning” and not “video games are great sources of learning”?

Comment: This product is two things: it is a clock and a radio. -- What are video games? Video games are one of the things that you can learn from – they are a source of learning. Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In "It's two things", "it" is a single object. The two things are different ways to categorize that one object. The verb agrees with the subject.

> It's two things: a floor wax and a desert topping.

If you actually had multiple objects, the pronoun would be "they", not "it", and you would use a plural verb.

In the video game example, "great source of learning" refers to the entire collection of games, not individual games, so it's singular. But we still use a plural verb because "video games" is plural.

Actually, I think both "a great source" and "great sources" would be acceptable, since you can treat them as a collective or as individual games.

Comment: +1 An SNL classic!